# Problems with jQuery Plugin

Tags: jquery, plugins

I have made a jQuery plugin, but it doesn't work properly. The results are not consistent. Sometimes it does work, but sometimes not.  I think the problem may be that some of the variables don't load fast enough.

Hope someone can help. Thanks in advance.

```
(function($) {

    $.fn.showhide = function(options) {

        var defaults = {
                appear: true,
                speed: 500
            },
            settings = $.extend({}, defaults, options);

        this.each(function() {

            var $this = $(this),
                elementWidth = $this.width(),
                elementHeight = $this.height(),
                newWidth = 0,
                newHeight = 0,
                marginX = Math.floor(elementWidth / 2),
                marginY = Math.floor(elementHeight/ 2);

            if(settings.appear) {

                console.log(elementWidth + ' ' + elementHeight + ' ' + marginX + ' ' + marginY);

                $this.css({ width: newWidth + 'px', height: newHeight + 'px', margin: marginY + 'px ' + marginX + 'px' });
                $this.animate({ width: elementWidth + 'px', height: elementHeight + 'px', margin: '0px', opacity: 'show' }, settings.speed);

            } else {



            }

        });

        return this;

    }

})(jQuery);
```

**EDIT**

The plugin is used for my image uploader. When I upload an image it should appear in a fancy way. I use this plugin for uploading: valums.com/ajax-upload and `onComplete` I use my plugin to show the image.

Comment: You need to define what this jQuery plugin is supposed to do, and what you mean by "working". Also, a complete HTML example that uses this plugin will be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Correct me if I'm wrong:

1. An image upload form, using [AJAX Upload](http://valums.com/ajax-upload/), allows users to upload an image onto your server.
2. AJAX Upload calls an `onComplete` callback with the URI of the newly-uploaded image.
3. You create a new `img` DOM element with `src` set to the URI of the uploaded image.
4. The `img` DOM element is added to the document.
5. `showhide` is called on the `img` element.

If this is correct, then it explains why `elementWidth` and `elementHeight` are sometimes not correct. The problem is that the browser needs time to download the image, and `elementWidth` and `elementHeight` are not valid until the image has been fully loaded.

To fix this problem, I would try calling `showhide` in a `load` callback on the `img` that is registered before the `src` attribute is set:

```
var     $myNewImage = $('<li><img alt="" /></li>'),
        $i = $myNewImage.children('img');

$i.hide();
$myNewImage.rightClick(function(e) {
        // ....
});

$myNewImage.prependTo('.uploadedImages');
$('.uploadedImages li').each(function() {
        var indexNumber = $(this).index();
        $(this).children('img').attr('id', 'image_' + indexNumber);
});

$i.load(function() {
        $i.showhide({ appear: true });
});
$i.attr('src', 'uploads/thumbs/' + file);
```